# Python - script can't load modules and prevents interpreter from doing it too

Tags: python, path, python-import, python-module

I'm able to access the Python interpreter from the Terminal and import a module, and then a specific name from it

```
python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Nov 28 2018, 11:51:47) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
```

However, if I run a script `sklearn.py` that only contains:

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
```

or if I'm in the same folder as the script and try to run either `import sklearn` or `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris` on its own, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sklearn.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "/Users/Anonymous/Documents/sklearn.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.datasets'; 'sklearn' is not a package
```

I can also go to a different folder (e.g. `cd Downloads/`) and I'm able to `import sklearn` or `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris` from the interpreter again.

1) It seems like the very existence of the script is taking priority over the interpreter when I'm in the same folder

2) I'm confused why the script can't import the modules in the first place. I'm thinking it might be an issue with the way I set up my PATH as that was kind of hacky, but the interpreter seems to work as expected.

I'm on OS X 10.14.1. I recently edited my .bash_profile file with `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"` so I could access my homebrew version of python through the terminally more easily. I commented out the OS X defaults for Python so it looks like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
#export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
#export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
#export PATH
```

Comment: "However, if I run a script sklearn.py" - don't name your script that.

Comment: @user2357112 wow I feel really dumb. So I guess the actual module is called "sklearn.py" and by naming it that I've overridden it/confused the interpreter?

Comment: It's actually an `sklearn` folder, because the module is a package, but yes, you are hiding it.